# blocked on writing unit tests to a presenter that has BoxStore injected

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, objectbox, mockk

So here is the overview of my project:
module A contains:
- all boxstore data
- boxstore mock for unit tests in module A

module B contains:
- presenter that has BoxStore injected
- presenterTest needs to mock BoxStore

Followed this [link](https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-examples/blob/master/android-app/src/test/java/io/objectbox/example/AbstractObjectBoxTest.java) to mock BoxStore and it works fine when I wrote unit tests in module A. When it comes to creating the mock in module B I get NoClassDefFoundError which I understand since module B tests don't know about module A test objects.

So I did the following scenarios:

1. Added in gradle of module B:

> sourceSets {   test.java.srcDirs += [etc...] }

So that module B would know about mock objects of module A.

2. Duplicate mock of BoxStore in module B and use it in tests but BoxStore generates a java file under build folder and because of that I'm unable to create my mock since everything depends on MyObjectBox in order to generate a BoxStore.

Both methods failed :(

Any ideas on how I can unblock myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Gradle, take a look at the [`java-test-fixtures`](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.2/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) plugin that has been introduced in Gradle 5.6.2. It introduces a new `testFixtures` source set where you can place various test data for a specific module and new DSL that allows other modules to reference this data in their tests. In your case, I imagine you'd put the test data in module A's `testFixtures` directory, and reference it from module B:

```
// module A
dependencies {
  testImplementation(testFixtures(project(":module-B")))
}
```

Comment: I've upgraded to 5.6.2 and I got this error "ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':module-A@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :module-B"